# ARC: Local variable responsible for heap growth in Allocations profile

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I programmatically set up a UINavigationBar with 2 Buttons on it.

```
-(void)setUpNavigationBar{
  //The Navbar
  UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar_gradient"];
  UINavigationBar *naviBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAINBAR_WIDTH, MAINBAR_HEIGHT)];
  [naviBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
  [naviBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  //Right Button
  UIButton *rButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  UIImage *rButImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_icon_menu2"];
  [rButton setBackgroundImage:rButImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [rButton addTarget: self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleRightView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [rButton setFrame:CGRectMake(MAINBAR_BUTTON_X, MAINBAR_BUTTON_Y, MAINBAR_BUTTON_WIDTH, MAINBAR_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
  UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:rButton];

  //Left Button
  UIButton *lButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  UIImage *lButImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_icon_menu1"];
  [lButton setBackgroundImage:lButImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [lButton addTarget: self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleLeftView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [lButton setFrame:CGRectMake(MAINBAR_BUTTON_X, MAINBAR_BUTTON_Y, MAINBAR_BUTTON_WIDTH, MAINBAR_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
  UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:lButton];

  //Put it all together
  naviBarItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
  naviBarItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
  naviBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:naviBarItem,nil];

  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;

  [self.view addSubview:naviBar];

  // This was my approach preventing the heap growth.
  rightButton = nil;
  leftButton = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self setUpNavigationBar];
}
```

I profile the app via instruments and take Heapshots (they´re called "Generations") in XCode 5 now. I want to solve the issues of my own objects first and hope the other heap growth issues just "cascade" from my own objects.

So I see there´s UIBarButtonItem increasing the heap by 448 bytes each time I close and open the app (This is the routine after I take a heapshot). Since there are 4 objects living, it seems like the objects don´t get released, I´m using `ARC`

**The problem is my heap is growing by approximately 200 kb each time I close and open the app. Here is the memory leak:**

[image: Instruments Allocations]

Digging deeper I see it´s the UIBarButtonItem from my `setUpNavigationBar` function.

[image]

So my question is how to I prevent the memory leak here? Since ARC is enabled, I can´t release the object myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you're making is that you're creating a new navigation bar each time you enter `setUpNavigationBar`. You create the navigation bar and then add it as a subview, which means that it gets retained, and you lose the reference to the navigation bar so you can never remove and release it.

I don't know why that method is being called multiple times, since you only call it from `viewDidLoad`, but potentially you're handling low-memory strangely.

You should be storing the navigation bar as a property. In your class' interface use this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationBar *naviBar;
```

And then change your code to this:

```
-(void)setUpNavigationBar{
    if (!self.naviBar)
    {
        //The Navbar
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar_gradient"];
        UINavigationBar *naviBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAINBAR_WIDTH, MAINBAR_HEIGHT)];
        self.naviBar = naviBar;
        [naviBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
        [naviBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        //Right Button
        UIButton *rButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *rButImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_icon_menu2"];
        [rButton setBackgroundImage:rButImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rButton addTarget: self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleRightView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rButton setFrame:CGRectMake(MAINBAR_BUTTON_X, MAINBAR_BUTTON_Y, MAINBAR_BUTTON_WIDTH, MAINBAR_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:rButton];

        //Left Button
        UIButton *lButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *lButImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_icon_menu1"];
        [lButton setBackgroundImage:lButImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [lButton addTarget: self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleLeftView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [lButton setFrame:CGRectMake(MAINBAR_BUTTON_X, MAINBAR_BUTTON_Y, MAINBAR_BUTTON_WIDTH, MAINBAR_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
        UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:lButton];

        //Put it all together
        naviBarItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
        naviBarItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
        naviBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:naviBarItem,nil];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;

        [self.view addSubview:naviBar];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we really need `// This was my approach preventing the heap growth.
        rightButton = nil;
        leftButton = nil;` ?

Comment: I copied it on purpose. I thought those may be ivars or something. It really doesn't matter.